# Breaking loop in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

The user inputs sentences for which the number of words has to be counted. If the number is greater than three the sentence should be considered *Long*. If three or fewer then *Short*.

I know how to do that, but the rest of the task says *make a loop* so the user can input sentences until he inputs "n". The problem is I when I input "n" it counts it, but that "n" shouldn't be counted. (It should be a `break` statement.) How can I break that loop before counting the letter "n"?

```
#!/bin/bash
recenica=0
while [ $recenica != "n" ]
do
    echo Unesite recenicu:
    read recenica
    if [ $recenica = "n" ]; then # ->>>>> this doesn't work
        break
    fi  
    echo $recenica > datoteka
    br=$(wc -l datoteka | cut -c1-2)
    echo recenica ima $br rijeci
    if [ $br -gt 3 ] 
    then
        echo $recenica > Duge.Recenice.IB
    elif [ $br -le 3 ] 
    then
        echo $recenica > Kratke.Recenice.IB
    else
        echo Molimo unijeti nešto
    fi  
done
```

Comment: It is too much effort to understand what you're asking. Please use  punctuation and white space.

Comment: Show your code so far.

Comment: When people say "show your code" they mean "update your question and *please* use proper formatting", because dumping your code in a comment is unreadable.

Comment: @IvanBarbarić I rewrote the non-code part to make it make sense to me. Let me know if you think it's wrong.

Comment: @kojiro You get 10 saint points for today :-)

Comment: @prodigitalson oh, are those worth more than SO rep? >:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use quotes around symbols that expand to more than one word (contain spaces)... this works:

```
#!/bin/bash
recenica=0
while [ "$recenica" != "n" ] # koristiti dvostruke navodnike ovdje
do
    echo Unesite recenicu:
    read recenica
    if [ "$recenica" = "n" ]; then # koristiti dvostruke navodnike ovdje
        break
    fi  
    echo $recenica > datoteka
    br=$(wc -l datoteka | cut -c1-2)
    echo recenica ima $br rijeci
    if [ $br -gt 3 ] 
    then
        echo $recenica > Duge.Recenice.IB
    elif [ $br -le 3 ] 
    then
        echo $recenica > Kratke.Recenice.IB
    else
        echo Molimo unijeti nešto
    fi  
done
```

Comment: Note that the `echo $recenica > datoteka` will create a one line file, so `wc -l` is only ever going to return `1` for the number of lines.  There's also the trick that `wc -l < datoteka` (making `wc` read from standard input) means that no file name is echoed, which simplifies the analysis (no need for `cut`).

Comment: thank you it is simple and easy just like I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `read` is that it will read the entire line and place the contents in `recenica`. With one word this is fine for the test:

```
while [ $recenica != "n" ]
```

However, if you have read more than one word, then the test will fail due to `[: too many arguments` (as noted by amdn in his answer regarding quoting)

When you enter `n` you care only about the first word, so limit your test accordingly using `parameter expansion/substring extraction`:

```
while [ ${recenica%% *} != "n" ]; do
```

That allows you to let the `while` loop control the `break` logic reducing the entire structure of your code to:

```
#!/bin/bash
recenica=0
while [ ${recenica%% *} != "n" ]
do
    echo Unesite recenicu:
    read recenica

    echo $recenica > datoteka
    br=$(wc -l datoteka | cut -c1-2)
    echo recenica ima $br rijeci

    if [ $br -gt 3 ] 
    then
        echo $recenica > Duge.Recenice.IB
    elif [ $br -le 3 ] 
    then
        echo $recenica > Kratke.Recenice.IB
    else
        echo Molimo unijeti nešto
    fi  
done
```

There are a number of ways to do this, but this approach is fine.